# how to fix Datetime picker with masked input gives blank screen in safari?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, popup, redux-form, maskedinput

In redux-form i want to use datetime picker with manual date entry enabled. I have used maskediinput for proper format. It is working fine with all the browsers for normal page.

When clicking on the input it gives blank screen in modal specific for safari. I can't find what is the issue with safari-modal-datepicker-maskedinput !

```
renderDateTimePicker = ({ input: { onChange, value }, showTime, id, meta, isRequired, readOnly,inputReadOnly }) => {

    return (<div> <DateTimePicker
        inputProps={{
            component: props => <MaskedInput {...props}  readOnly={readOnly || inputReadOnly} type="text"
                     mask={[ /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/,".",/\d/, /\d/, ".", /\d/, /\d/ ]} />
        }}
        onChange={onChange}
        format="YYYY.MM.DD"
        time={showTime}
        id={id}
        name="completion_date"
        className="date_click"
        placeholder={isRequired === true ? id + " *" : id}
        value={!value ? null : new Date(value)}
    />{this.renderError(meta)}
    </div>
    );
}
```

Here is my package.json file :

```
{
    "name": "reduxapi",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@devexpress/dx-grid-core": "^1.10.1",
        "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^1.10.1",
        "@devexpress/dx-react-grid": "^1.10.1",
        "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui": "^1.10.1",
        "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
        "@types/bootstrap.v3.datetimepicker": "^4.17.46",
        "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
        "ag-grid-community": "^20.0.0",
        "ag-grid-react": "^20.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "bootstrap": "^3.4.0",
        "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
        "cryptr": "^4.0.2",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^4.0.1",
        "faker": "^4.1.0",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^1.11.2",
        "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
        "jspdf-autotable": "^3.1.1",
        "jwt-simple": "^0.5.5",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
        "query-string": "^6.2.0",
        "react": "^16.7.0",
        "react-autocomplete": "^1.8.1",
        "react-autocomplete-input": "^1.0.10",
        "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
        "react-awesome-modal": "^2.0.5",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
        "react-confirm-alert": "^2.4.1",
        "react-csv": "^1.1.1",
        "react-data-grid": "^5.0.5",
        "react-data-grid-addons": "^5.0.5",
        "react-datepicker": "^2.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
        "react-encrypt": "^1.0.1",
        "react-grid-layout": "^0.16.6",
        "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
        "react-moment": "^0.8.4",
        "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
        "react-select": "^2.4.1",
        "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
        "react-to-print-advanced": "^2.1.2",
        "react-widgets": "^4.4.10",
        "react-widgets-moment": "^4.0.27",
        "react-widgets-moment-localizer": "^1.0.2",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-form": "^8.1.0",
        "redux-multilanguage": "^0.1.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
    ]
}
```

Comment: if  you are using the materila-ui, you can test this sample:: https://codesandbox.io/s/xvzollx44q
if not, provide package.json and version of safari

Comment: safari version is 12

Comment: Did you test the sample that  i provided?